# OnOptionsItemSelected is not called in Xamarin.Android API 24+ (Android 7+)

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-7.0-nougat, appcompatactivity, android-7.1-nougat

I'm developing an app with *Xamarin.Android* that was working fine until the API 23 (Android 6.0):

This is my **OnCreate** event:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    SetTheme(Resource.Style.MyCustomThemeCompat);
    base.OnCreate(bundle);

    base.SetActionBar(FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarMain));
    ActionBar.Title = Title;

    ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);

    ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
}
```

And this my event **OnOptionsItemSelected**, which is never called since the API 24+ (Android 7+):

```
public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
{
    switch (item.ItemId)
    {
        case Android.Resource.Id.Home:
            if (MDrawerLayout.IsDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.Start))
            {
                MDrawerLayout.CloseDrawers();
            }
            else
            {
                MDrawerLayout.OpenDrawer(GravityCompat.Start);
            }

            return true;
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```

My custom style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyCustomThemeCompat" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">#01579B</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimaryDark">#01579B</item>
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#0277BD</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#FAFAFA</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#BDBDBD</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">#424242</item>
    <item name="android:elevation">4dp</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

I haven't found any example or explanation of any change that I should do in my code. Most of examples use some Menus, but I don't need any. Also, I'm working with an **AppCompatActivity** and a **Toolbar**.

Right now, I just have a Hamburger menu in order to display the NavigationDrawer.

**Toolbar:**

[image: Hamburger menu]

**Navigation Drawer opened:**

[image: Navigation Drawer]

Out here is a small example of the full code:

[https://github.com/FANMixco/NavigationDrawerError](https://web.archive.org/web/20180627151722/https://github.com/FANMixco/NavigationDrawerError)

Did anyone experience it before? Thanks for your advice.

Comment: What is your `MyCustomThemeCompat`? please post your code.

Comment: Delete the `async` in your `OnCreate` method.

Comment: Hi @YorkShen-MSFT the async is related to another action, I didn't add that part, but I don't think it has any connection.

Comment: Also, @YorkShen-MSFT I added my style.

Comment: I create a demo but can't reproduce your problem, would you mind share a basic demo to reproduce this problem ? To make sure we are verifying the exact same thing you are using.

Comment: Sure, I'll upload it to GitHub as soon as I'm back (maybe in 6 hours), just remember it only happens in Android 7+ if you try another emulator it won't happen and the hamburger menu will open as expected. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT I added the code and an example in my GitHub. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, modify your `toolbarMain.xml` from `Android.Widget.Toolbar` to `Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar` :

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbarMain"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"/>
```

Second, in your `MainActivity` :

```
//base.SetActionBar(FindViewById<Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarMain));
//ActionBar.Title = "Típicos Salvadoreños";
        
//ActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
//ActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

MDrawerLayout = FindViewById<DrawerLayout>(Resource.Id.drawer_layout);

var mToolbar = FindViewById<Android.Support.V7.Widget.Toolbar>(Resource.Id.toolbarMain);
SetSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
SupportActionBar.SetDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
SupportActionBar.SetHomeAsUpIndicator(Resource.Drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
SupportActionBar.Title = "Típicos Salvadoreños";
```

Then, `OnOptionsItemSelected` will be called when you click the Hamburger menu.

[Effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySzOd.gif).

### Update :

You could read the [ActionBarDrawerToggle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html) document, notice  the two constructors there. The `Toolbar` type is `android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: I have a couple of questions, why the normal toolbar doesn't work? Could you explain me? Also, which library should use for the v7? I recall the last time I couldn't use it. Thanks

Comment: @FedericoNavarrete, the library is `Xamarin.Android.Support.v7.AppCompat`, you have installed this library in your project , you could directly use it.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but could you tell me why cannot I use the normal toolbar?